# How to find the number of excution of this function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to find the number of this function executions. The function in a cc file is:

```
CacheSetLRU::CacheSetLRU( 
      CacheBase::cache_t cache_type,
      UInt32 associativity, UInt32 blocksize, CacheSetInfoLRU* set_info, UInt8 num_attempts)
   : CacheSet(cache_type, associativity, blocksize)
   , m_num_attempts(num_attempts)
   , m_set_info(set_info)
{
    m_lru_bits = new UInt8[m_associativity];
   for (UInt32 i = 0; i < m_associativity; i++)
      m_lru_bits[i] = i;

}
```

the related Header file has the following lines:

```
class CacheSetLRU : public CacheSet
{
   public:
      CacheSetLRU(CacheBase::cache_t cache_type,
            UInt32 associativity, UInt32 blocksize, CacheSetInfoLRU* set_info, UInt8 num_attempts);
      virtual ~CacheSetLRU();

      virtual UInt32 getReplacementIndex(CacheCntlr *cntlr);
      void updateReplacementIndex(UInt32 accessed_index);

   protected:
      const UInt8 m_num_attempts;
      UInt8* m_lru_bits;
      CacheSetInfoLRU* m_set_info;
      void moveToMRU(UInt32 accessed_index);
};
```

I did declare a static integer and got the numbers with cout but I want only **the last number** and i don't know how to do this. I have searched and dug every forum but the approaches didn't outcome on my code. This code is a part of an open-source simulator's core codes.
Any help or hint will be appreciated kindly.

Comment: Did you try printing the static variable as the last thing to happen in `main`? That will probably get you the last number.

Comment: What specifically preventing you from declaring a counter, incrementing the counter in this function, and then printing the value of this counter before `main()` terminates? What exactly do you mean by "I want only the last number"? There's only one number here, the number of times this function got called. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Global `int counter = 0;`  At the point of interest `++counter;`.  Just before main finishes, `std::cout << counter << "\n";`

Comment: @john I cannot declare a new main function because the main function is declared in another code of the simulator hence making the simulator gets duplication of declaration error, due to the simulators restrictions. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, as I mentioned this code, is part of a code of thousands of code files of a simulator and I cannot declare a new ```main()``` function because there is a one in another code file. I can use this code at this function:
```static int i;```
```std::cout<<"We had " << ++i << " replacement in LRU!\n"```
but this code prints every time ```i``` change and I want just the last number with respect to the restriction of ```main()``` re-declaration.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nobody said "declare a new `main()`". Where exactly did I suggest that? Increment a counter in the constructor, and add one line to existing main that prints the value of the counter, just before it returns. Or declare a small class whose destructor prints it, and instantiate it in main, so no matter how and why main returns, the counter's value gets printed just before the program terminates. This is very simple.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks Sam, I am working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create yourself a `Recorder` type that you place as an object with static lifetime in your function and have its destructor output the number of uses. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Recorder {
  T data;
  ~Recorder() {
    std::cout << data << "\n";
  }
};

struct Foo {
  void bar() const {
    static Recorder<unsigned> recorder = {0};
    recorder.data += 1;
    (void)(1+2); // do your thing in your function ...
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.bar();
  Foo().bar();
}
```

Running this produces:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -O3 a.cpp && ./a.out
2
```

---

Note that you can add as much syntactic sugar to this as you like, and also you can instantiate it for as many functions as you like. Giving it some kind of identifier during construction. For example:

```
template <typename T, typename Identifier = std::string>
struct Recorder {
  T data;
  Identifier identifier = Identifier();
  ~Recorder() {
    std::cout << identifier << ": called " << data << " times\n";
  }
};
```